How to escape backslash and quotes in powershell for aws-cli
Hi I'm working in a windows powershell script:
$startDate = "2024-11-07T11:00:00Z"
$endDate = "2024-11-07T11:40:00Z"

$startTimestamp = [int]([DateTimeOffset]::Parse($startDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds())
$endTimestamp = [int]([DateTimeOffset]::Parse($endDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds())
  
$logGroup = "logGroup"
$queryString = "fields @log, @timestamp, @message | limit 10"

$queryResult = aws logs start-query --log-group-name "$logGroup" --start-time $startTimestamp --end-time $endTimestamp --query-string "$queryString" --region us-east-1 | ConvertFrom-Json

$queryId = $queryResult.queryId
Write-Output "Query ID: $queryId"

$queryResults = aws logs get-query-results --query-id $queryId --region us-east-1

Write-Output "Resultados de la consulta:"
Write-Output $queryResults

if I execute the script it works, but what I want is to use this query in order to get a count of httpCodes:
fields @log, @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "\"httpCode\":4"
| parse @message '"message":"*' as Message
| parse Message '\"httpCode\":*,' as httpCode
| stats count() as CodeCount by httpCode
| sort CodeCount desc
| display CodeCount, httpCode
| limit 10

but I'm not sure how to escape the especial character so it can be used by aws-cli, I've tried the backtick (`) but it is not working I'm getting an error like

An error occurred (MalformedQueryException) when calling the
StartQuery operation: unexpected symbol found : at line 1 and position
172

Regards!

The version is 5.1.19041.5007, in the query the " and \ are not escaped, both are part of the pattern so I need to scape them in order to pass them to the aws-cli query. something like:
aws logs start-query --log-group-name "logGroup" --start-time 1730990829 --end-time 1731016029 --query-string "fields @log, @timestamp, @message | filter @message like "`"httpCode\":4`" | limit 10"


Let's start with a simplified, verbatim version of the string you're trying to pass:
Note:

I'm only focusing on the aspect of escaping the embedded " characters in the string - I cannot speak to whether your query is otherwise correct (e.g., @message vs. Message, the extra " in '"message":"*', which I've omitted below).

fields @log, @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "\"httpCode\":4"
| parse @message '"message":*' as Message


The string you need to pass to as an argument to an external program in Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1), as well as in PowerShell (Core) 7 up to version 7.2.x:

must first satisfy PowerShell's own syntax requirements...

... and - unfortunately - must also have embedded " characters (and situationally \ characters, namely if they directly precede ") \-escaped (this requirement no longer applies to PowerShell v7.3+; see this answer for background information).


Therefore, using a verbatim here string to avoid the need for PowerShell-specific escaping:
# In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.2.x
$queryString = @'
fields @log, @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like \"\\\"httpCode\\\":4\"
| parse @message '\"message\":*' as Message
'@

Note:

The above uses a verbatim here-string (@'<newline>...<newline>'@); whenever you need string interpolation, use the expandable variant (@"<newline>...<newline>"@).


Great!! thank you so much mklement0 this is what I was looking, now I can do the query, thank you!!

sorry for disturbing you again, do you know how can I pass the value though a variable, something like
$httpCodePrefix = 4
Query = @' fields @log, @timestamp, @message | filter @message like \"\\\"httpCode\\\":$httpCodePrefix\" | parse @message '\"message\":*' as Message | parse Message '\\\"httpCode\\\":*,' as httpCode | stats count() as CodeCount by httpCode | sort CodeCount desc | display CodeCount, httpCode | limit 10 '@
So I can change do different code searches, in the way that I did it above the variable name is taken like a part of the pattern instead of the value

Use an expandable here-string: After the opening and before the closing @, replace ‘ with “
